# Why "git add . " stage deleted files also

Tags: git, github, repository

I'm working on a group project and there is a file that contains settings for something. All I need to delete that file and not commit that deletion to any commit in the local and remote repo. I saw "git add ." doesn't commit deleted files to the staging area. But it does stage deleted files. I'm using git bash on windows. How to solve this.

Comment: `git reset -- <path/to/file>` to unstage its deletion.

Comment: Or just add the other files only.

Comment: So I have to do this every time I add files to the stage? Is there any method to avoid that file when committing?

Comment: maybe [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) would help?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you're asking *why Git does this*, or *how to avoid having Git do this*.  Those are two different questions.

#### Why Git does this

The reason that Git does this is because `git add` means *make the staging copy of the file match the working tree copy of the file*.  If the working tree copy of the file is *removed*, the way to make the staging copy match is to remove the staging copy as well.

Remember, the staging area—which Git also calls the *index*, or sometimes the *cache* as in `git diff --cached` or `git rm --cached`—contains a copy of *every file taken from the current commit, ready to go into the next commit*.  These files, extracted from the current commit, are *also* in your *working tree*.  The difference between the staging copy and the working tree copy comes about because you make changes directly to your working tree.  The `git add` command then *updates the staged copy to match* so that the change is ready to be committed.

#### How to avoid having Git do this

**In general**, the *easy* way to avoid having Git update the staging copy of some file is to avoid updating the working tree copy of that file.  So if you don't want Git to remove the staging copy, don't remove the working tree copy either.  If you don't want Git to make some change to the staging copy, don't make that same change to the working tree copy.

If you must make some working-tree change, but don't want it to go into the staging area, the next-simplest method is to avoid running `git add` on that file.  That means avoiding `git add .`, which adds all files at this point in the working tree and below (recursively).

In some *very special* cases, you can (ab)use the internal *skip-worktree* bit, which is meant for Git's use in the sparse checkout code.  By setting the skip-worktree bit for some file that exists in Git's index, you tell Git *not* to update the index copy from the working tree copy.  This includes having Git *avoid* removing the index copy just because the working tree copy is missing—which is something sparse checkout must do, since sparse checkout works by *setting* the skip-worktree bit on the not-extracted-to-working-tree files in the first place.

If you do this manual setting of skip-worktree, you need to avoid using sparse checkout, since Git will set and clear the skip-worktree bit on its own when using sparse checkout.  So be careful with this.  Note, too, that you can't *see* this bit directly,<sup>1</sup> so if you *do* start using this, make sure you do not *forget that you have done it*.

To set the skip-worktree bit for some particular index copy of some particular file, use the `git update-index` command.  To *clear* the bit, use the `git update-index` command again:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree f1     # stop looking at worktree f1
git update-index --no-skip-worktree f2  # resume looking at worktree f2
```

---

<sup>1</sup>You *can* see the skip-worktree bit using `git ls-files`.  This is also true for the assume-unchanged bit, which has a similar though not quite identical function.  [It's a little tricky though.](https://github.com/chris3torek/scripts/blob/master/git-flagged)